Recommended method to assign permission sets in reg handler
we are making the switch to using permission sets instead of roles, and we keep getting an error when trying to assign a permission set during user creation in our reg handler. We have had to create a separate process to assign permission sets after it sees a new user is created. The issue is that we have a loading screen that the user must sit on while this process happens. We've observed this taking up to 60 seconds.
What is the recommended way of assigning permissions/permission sets to new users? Documentation has not been helpful.
